# Dependency Injection Ensure that you have not accidentally loaded the same module twice

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using Ninject for Dependency Injection. I have to call two identical classes in the constructor.

```cs
public EsyonluAntennaManager(
    IModbusActuatorService dksEkbService1, IModbusActuatorService dksEkbService2)
{
   _dksEkbService1  = dksEkbService1;
   _dksEkbService2  = dksEkbService2;
}
```

IModbusActuatorService and ModbusActuatorManager are connected to each other.

```cs
public ModbusActuatorManager(
    ISocketDeviceDal socketDeviceDal,
    IDataBaseErrorService dataBaseError,
    IDataBaseService dataBase,
    Code code)
{
    _socketDeviceDal = socketDeviceDal;
    _dataBaseError = dataBaseError;
    _dataBase = dataBase;
    _code = code;
}
```

The `ISocketDeviceDal`'s constructor does not take any arguments. `IDataBaseErrorService` and `IDataBaseService` have only one argument in constructor.

```cs
Bind<IDataBaseService>().To<DataBaseManager>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("path", _pathDbLog);
Bind<IDataBaseErrorService>().To<DataBaseErrorManager>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("path", _pathDbError);            
Bind<ISocketDeviceDal>().To<SocketDeviceDal>();
Bind<IModbusActuatorService>().To<ModbusActuatorManager>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("code", _code);

Bind<IKamciAntennaService>().To<KamciAntennaManager>();
```

I observed Injection Ensure that you have not accidentally loaded the same module twice this error. How can I do that? How can Inject `IKamciAntennaService` and `KamciAntennaManager`

```cs
public static T GetService<T>(
    string pathDbError, string pathDbLog, Code _code,Code _code1)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(
        new DependecyInjection(pathDbError, pathDbLog, _code),
        new DependecyInjection(pathDbError, pathDbLog, _code1));
        
    return kernel.Get<T>();
}
```

**UPDATED**
I fixed the problem.

```
        public EsyonluAntennaManager(
[Named("Local")]IModbusActuatorService dksEkbService1, 
[Named("Remote")] IModbusActuatorService dksEkbService2)
        {
           _dksEkbService1  = dksEkbService1;
           _dksEkbService2  = dksEkbService2;
        }
```

```
            Bind<IModbusActuatorService>().To<ModbusActuatorManager>().InTransientScope()
.Named("Remote").WithConstructorArgument("code", _codeRemote);

            Bind<IModbusActuatorService>().To<ModbusActuatorManager>().InTransientScope()
.Named("Local").WithConstructorArgument("code", _codeLocal);
```

Comment: Take a look at the [When method](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-arbitrary-elements-of-the-resolution-request-context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common solution to this issue is to employ the factory pattern.

You create a factory, that based on some paramter set, during runtime, decide which of the classes to use, and then you merely dependency inject that factory.

```
public interface IDksServiceFactory
{
   IDkservice ResolveDksService()//add some input paraameters?
} 

public DksServiceFactory : IDksServiceFactory
{
    public IDkservice ResolveDksService()
    {
        if()//something?
        {
            return  new DksEkbService1(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return new DksEkbService2(); 
        }
    }
}

public interface IDksService() // implement the interface for your "identical" services.
{
   
}

public class DksEkbService1 : IDksService
{
  
}

public class DksEkbService2 : IDksService
{
  
}
```

and then in your services, you just add the factory, and use the "resolve method" on the object from your constructor to find the class you need.